# function able to call any other variable from array in pagescontroller

Tags: php, cakephp

It's my first time to link web design to my code which generated by cakephp framework
and iam trying since three days to show the images in the site as it is in the desgin .. but i foiled

The idea is an appearance of a text with an image for 4 times

there is the code which made by the designer

```
<div class="container">
                    <h1>TITILE</h1>
                    <div class="row">
                    <!--Start testmonial carousel !-->
                    <div id="carousel_testmonial" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <p class="lead"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
                        <span>News Title</span>
                      </div>

                   <div class="item ">
                        <p class="lead"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
                        <span>News Title</span>
                      </div>
<div class="item ">
                            <p class="lead"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
                            <span>News Title</span>
                          </div>
<div class="item ">  <p class="lead"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
                            <span>News Title</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel_testmonial" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img src="image/4.jpg"  alt="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel_testmonial" data-slide-to="1"><img  class="img-responsive" src="image/3.jpg" alt="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel_testmonial" data-slide-to="2"><img  class="img-responsive" src="image/4.jpg"  alt="3"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel_testmonial" data-slide-to="3"><img class="img-responsive" src="image/3.jpg"  alt="4"></li>
                  </ol>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

---

I think i can use `foreach` to do that . like this one

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <?php $active = false; ?>
        <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
            <div class="item <?php if (!$active){ echo "active"; $active = true; } ?>">

                <?php echo $this->Html->image($image); ?>


            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
```

but i foiled and i want to know a function like these `image($image);`  ((which go to the path of images in the array $images))
to be able to call any other variable 
or if you can give me hints to be able to sove this

and thanks alot ...

Comment: `debug` $image and place the output in your question.

Comment: sorry, but i cant understand how to make this

Comment: `debug($images);` Outside of the `<div class="carousel-inner"`

Answer (score 0):

The HtmlHelper needs a path to the image as the first argument. 
As said by [Andre Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597237/andre-santiago) you need to use the debug tool to see what the $image variable is actually containing and make sure that it is a proper path.

You can write:

```
debug($images);
```

This should output your array of images into a readable format that you can check to make sure the proper path is being passed.

You may need to change some configuration so first see the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html#basic-debugging) for reference.

If you are still having trouble please show the code where you are setting the $images variable. Also if it's the case that images are just broken, it could be a permissions issue.